# Having the same camera in all scenes

Tags: unity

I have 100 scenes, each scene has a camera, but I want only the camera from scene 1 to exist in each scene that I appear in.

I use the function DontDestroyOnLoad() to make the camera exist in each scene but I always find my self with another camera that I don't want.

Any ideas? thank you in advance.

Comment: Any one? I need help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you remove the camera in every scene except the first one. Assuming you HAVE to keep the first camera for some reason, you probably then need to re position the camera somewhere in your subsequent scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to have one "master scene" with the camera (and anything else you want to have in every level, like UI elements for example) and then load the individual levels additively with [`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(scene, LoadSceneMode.Additive)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html). You will then have two scenes at once loaded in your game. If you want to switch levels, you can unload the current level-scene with [`SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(scene)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync.html).

Remember to wait until `UnloadSceneAsync` has finished before calling `LoadSceneAsync`. Otherwise you might occasionally see objects from the new scene interact with objects from the old which were not deleted yet. You can do that by examining the [`AsyncOperation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation.html) object returned by `LoadSceneAsync` or by assigning a callback method to [`SceneManager.sceneUnloaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneUnloaded.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use singleton pattern or add some simple functionality destroying newly created camera if it's already present in scene.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to achieve:

***You want to preserve the camera through all the levels in you scene***

Then what you want to use is a script with [Object.dontDestroyOnLoad()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

***You want to use a camera in all your levels, but don't want to preserve the object throughout all the scenes***

This is a work for prefabs. You make a prefab of you camera and apply components, scripts and so on to it. You have to remember to have a "camera" prefab object in every scene. If you want to make changes to it, you just have to modify the prefab, not all the "camera" objects in the scenes